# Left join and Count from tables

Tags: mysql, count

I have 3 tables

Table Ploeg with

```
PloegID | Name |
5       | name1|
2       | name2|
```

Table Round with

```
ID | PloegID | Timestamp
 1 |   5     |  xxxxxx
 2 |   2     |  xxxxxx
 3 |   5     |  xxxxxx
 4 |   5     |  xxxxxx
 5 |   2     |  xxxxxx
```

Table Averages with

```
ID | PloegID | Speed
 1 |   5     |   4
 2 |   2     |   3
 3 |   5     |   6
 4 |   5     |   2
 5 |   2     |   3
```

What i need is a table with

```
PloegID | Average of Speed for each ploegID | Name | Count of Ploegid in table Round.
   5    |            6                      | name1 |       3
   2    |            3                      | name2 |       2
```

I have this code , but its counts the rounds wrong

```
SELECT g.ploegid, AVG(g.speed) as average,l.name ,count(r.ploegid)   AS rondes 
FROM averages as g
left join Ploeg as l on  l.id = g.ploegid
left join Round as r on   r.ploegid = l.ploegid
GROUP BY ploegid
ORDER BY g.ploegid;
```

The speed is correct , but the count not.

Comment: provide some sample data set ?

Comment: what is ```g.ploegnr```? Maybe you should post queries that at least in your db do not create errors. Finally, i guess you count all rows in r, since you do a ```LEFT JOIN```. Maybe an ```INNER JOIN``` would do what you want?

Comment: Did you run the query you posted? I still doubt it. l.naam -> spelling, GROUP BY ploegid -> which one? g, l r?

Comment: SELECT g.ploegid, AVG(g.speed) as average,l.naam
    FROM averages as g
    left join Ploeg as l on  l.id = g.ploegid
    GROUP BY g.ploegid
    ORDER BY g.ploegid;

Comment: it's g.ploegid . iv'e run the query with the dutch values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have multiple rows in each table that match `ploegid`.  Hence, you are getting a cartesian product that is throwing off the calculations.  I would also suggest you start the `left join`s with `Ploeg`, because that seems to be the driving table:

```
SELECT l.ploegid, g.average, l.name, r.rondes 
FROM Ploeg l left join
     (select ploegid, avg(g.speed) as average
      from averages g
      group by ploegid
     ) g
     on  l.id = g.ploegid left join
     (select ploegid, count(*) as rondes
      from Round r
      group by ploegid
     ) r
     on r.ploegid = l.ploegid
ORDER BY l.ploegid;
```

Comment: Now it's count the ploegid in table round Correct , but now the avg is wrong

Comment: sorry , my mistake if i translated to dutch , your answer is correct ;-)